# GTK# how to correctly clean widgets, memory leak (Glib.toggleref, Glib.signal)

Tags: c#, .net, memory, gtk, gtk#

I'm actually working on a software powered by GTK# 2.12, we have some memory leaks on it and I'm searching how to improve that.

I made a small app to test the correct way to get rid of a widget. I'm creating 10 000 Labels and then I delete them.

Here's my Label class:

```
namespace test_gtk_objects
{

    public class TimeLabel : Label
    {

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected DateTime _time;



        public TimeLabel(DateTime time)
        {
            Time = time;
        }


        ~TimeLabel()
        {
            Dispose(false);

            Console.WriteLine("Called dispose(false) of class" + this.ToString());
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        //dispose
        public override void Dispose()
        {
           // Console.WriteLine("Called dispose(true) of class" + this.ToString());
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                Hide();
                Unrealize();
                Unparent();
                Unmap();
                Destroy();
                Unref();
                Console.WriteLine("ref: " + RefCount.ToString()); 

                // Free any other managed objects here.
                //
            }
            disposed = true;
            base.Dispose();
        }

        protected void display(Label input_label)
        {
            input_label.Text = _time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        }


        internal DateTime Time
        {
            get { return _time; }
            set
            {
                if (_time != value)
                {
                    _time = value;
                    display(this);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

as you can see I have overridden the dispose method as suggested. I also tried some way to free most of the widget (especially with the unref() ) to be sure the widget is not linked to something else.

In my main window, I just create thoses labels in à list and remove them by calling the Dispose method on each of them. All my widgets seem to be deleted, but I always have some **Glib. toggleref**, **Glib. Signal** as you can see in my memory snapshot:

[Memory snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lURAx.png)

I don't have an idea how I can get a rid on it if you can help me with that problem it will be very appreciated

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally edited GTK sharp library to remove toggleref when I destroy a widget by calling Glib Dispose in the destroy method. My objects count doesn't grow up fast and all my objects are deleted when needed !